# Java homework: Print Arrays with stored random numbers in it

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

I need some help for a class assignment. I dont want to be given the solution but rather to understand how i can solve this because i really dont get it even if it's simple.

I need to write a program that will have an Array with 10 elements(all of them integers). A random generated number will be set to each element and each number will be from 0-20. Next, i must print the position of the element of the array , the random number and as many asterisks as the value of the array.

It will look like this:

```
Array Value Asterisks
0     5     *****
1     15    ***************
```

I can generate the numbers and set store them to the Array but i cant print them according to the description. Could you please tell me what am i doing wrong?.

```
public class ForTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Method 1
        int[] myNumbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        //Method 2
        int[] randomNumbers = new int[10];
        String asterisk = "";

        for( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)
        {
            randomNumbers[index] = 1 + (int) ( Math.random() *20);
        } // end for

        for ( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)
        {
            switch (randomNumbers[index]) {
                case 1:
                asterisk = "*";
                System.out.println(myNumbers[0] + "\t-->\t" + randomNumbers + asterisk);
                break;
                case 2:
                asterisk = "**";
                System.out.println(myNumbers[1] + "\t-->\t" + randomNumbers + asterisk);
                break;
                case 3:
                asterisk = "***";
                System.out.println(myNumbers[2] + "\t-->\t" + randomNumbers + asterisk);
                break;
                case 4:
                asterisk = "****";
                System.out.println(myNumbers[3] + "\t-->\t" + randomNumbers + asterisk);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's start with this: `System.out.println(myNumbers[0] + "\t-->\t" + randomNumbers + asterisk);` .... the `randomNumbers` in this print statement is the whole array. What you want to print is an element of the array.

Comment: Instead of using a huge switch statement, you can set the number of asterisks to print in a for-loop running from `0` to `randomNumbers[index]`. This would also allow you to change the maximum random number without having to extend the switch statement even further.

Answer (score 1):

1) Let us start with the minimal code you need to solve your assignment:
   that is an array with 10 random numbers. I just copied what you already have

```
   public static void main(String [] args) {        
        int[] randomNumbers = new int[10];

        for( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
            randomNumbers[index] = 1 + (int) ( Math.random() *20);
        }            
    }
```

You do not need the second array called myNumbers; you can use the indices of your randomNumbers array instead

2) Let us now make another step and try to print the indices.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {        
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[10];

    for( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
        randomNumbers[index] = 1 + (int) ( Math.random() *20);
    }

    for ( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
        System.out.println(index);                
    }
}
```

this will output

```
0
1
2
...
```

3)If you now add the element at the specified index to the print statement you are half done

```
public static void main(String [] args) {        
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[10];

    for( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
        randomNumbers[index] = 1 + (int) ( Math.random() *20);
    }

    for ( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
        System.out.println(index + "\t" + randomNumbers[index]);                
    }
}
```

output

```
0   4
1   8
2   7
....
```

4) I guess you already know the difference between `System.out.println()` and `System.out.print()`. If not google is your friend. To print the asterisks you can add another for-loop in your last loop instead of a switch block

```
public static void main(String [] args) {        
        int[] randomNumbers = new int[10];

        for( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
            randomNumbers[index] = 1 + (int) ( Math.random() *20);
        }

        for ( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
            System.out.println(index +"\t"+randomNumbers[index]+"\t");
            for ( int x=1; x <= randomNumbers[index]; x++){                
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }
```

which will produce

```
0   4   
****1   11  
***********2    15  
***************3    8
...
```

5) not exatly what you need but very close. The println() jumps after printing to a new line while print() stays at the same line. To fix that use print() to print a line with the random numbers and asterisks and jump to a new line with an empty println() after the inner for-loop

```
public static void main(String [] args) {        
        int[] randomNumbers = new int[10];

        for( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
            randomNumbers[index] = 1 + (int) ( Math.random() *20);
        }

        for ( int index=0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++){
            System.out.print(index +"\t"+randomNumbers[index]+"\t");
            for ( int x=1; x <= randomNumbers[index]; x++){                
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another option for the last for-loop would be `for (int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++) {
   asterisk = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers[index]; i++) {
    asterisk += "*";
   }
   System.out.println(myNumbers[0] + "\t-->\t" + randomNumbers[index] + "\t" + asterisk);
  }`

Comment: Eritrean. First of all , thank you for providing the proper code and explaining every part of it. I've tried running your code and it went well until i added the last loop. Now i get this error: ForTest.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                for ( int x=1; x <= randomNumbers[index]; x++){
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable index
  location: class ForTest
1 error

Comment: @JoelLi  If you literally copied that last code snippet, it should run (it does for me)

Comment: @RobinTopper Well, i copied it and it worked. I must have typed something wrong i guess.

Answer (score 0):

In the end you want to print 10 Strings so it might be an idea to declare a String[] of size 10 at first.
This you can achieve with `String[] nameOfArray = new String[10];`

Then you can use one or multiple for loops to edit those strings:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

/* code to write the index position goes here
 * hint: use the variable i that is declared in the for-loop
 */

/* code to write the value goes here
 * hint: you can append text to a String of your String[] like this:
 * nameOfArray[i] = nameOfArray[i] + "text";
 * or even shorter:
 * nameOfArray[i] += "text";
 */

/* code to write asterisks goes here
 * hint: for(int j = 0; j<amountOfAsterisks; j++)
 */

}
```

If you want to have a table-like layout at the end you will have to add whitespace according to value length. Here is an example for adding whitespace to values smaller than 10:

```
if(number < 10)
    nameOfArray[positionInArray] += " ";
```

At the end you only need a loop to go through the array and print all the values.

Please note: what I explained here is easy to understand but not very efficient! (Eg one can: use only one loop instead of multiple loops, use Stringbuilders instead of Strings, do not create a String[] at all but directly print,...)

Comment: He already seems to understand how to get a properly formatted output using tabs. The last part of your answer is therefore unnecessary and actually more complicated than tabs

Comment: Tabs might fail, when passing the tab size while printing (though not in this exercise with restrictions to value size)
However I wanted also to create an overview to the entire exercise without leaving out the formatting @RobinTopper

Answer (score -3):

Here is one solution:

```
private static final String PATTERN = "********************";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Array Value Asterisks");
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).forEach(i -> {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 21);
        System.out.printf("%-6s%-6s%s\n", i, r, PATTERN.substring(0, r));
    });
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
Array Value Asterisks
1     10    **********
2     16    ****************
3     3     ***
4     9     *********
5     19    *******************
6     1     *
7     5     *****
8     16    ****************
9     8     ********
10    12    ************
```

Comment: Neat solutions, but as the OP said: _I dont want to be given the solution but rather to understand how i can solve this..._

Comment: @Robin: yes you are right, but I struggled to invent a puzzle pointing to the solution. I am sorry. Forgive me :)

Comment: You don't need to invent puzzles. You can give sound advice instead of trying to show off by solving trivial homework problems in a "fancy way". Considering how many students are actually asking for a ready-made solution, someone asking for *advice* instead of a solution is a refreshing change. If you want to impress people with your programming skills, go answer some harder questions.